# MySQL Stored procedure with one (OUT) value, requesting two values?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this god awful bug that I can't figure out for the life of me, whenever I run the following stored procedure it first requests two variables in, even though I only declared ONE as an out. If I remove all the inputs/outputs and set it to no inputs it still requests two inputs. The values out of these are always @A = null, @B=0.00

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this, any help would be greatly appreciated (it's probably something stupid like a missed semi or a syntax error, but I've looked and can't see anything). (code is supposed to traverse a data table and return the sum of the values, it's a school assignment so it has to be a procedure in this case (so no SELECT SUM(N) FROM TABLE))

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE P_TOTAL_PRICES (OUT  n_total_price DOUBLE(9,2))
BEGIN
-- declare primitives
    DECLARE PROD_PRICE DOUBLE(9,2);
    DECLARE FOUND BOOLEAN;

-- declare cursor for loop illiteration. 
    DECLARE SUM_PRODUCTS cursor for
    SELECT prices FROM PRODUCT;

    -- declare end if variable for cursor
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET FOUND = FALSE;

-- set core field vars and continue. 
    SET FOUND = TRUE;
    OPEN SUM_PRODUCTS;
    SET n_total_price=0; -- clean previous queries

    FETCH SUM_PRODUCTS INTO PROD_PRICE;
        WHILE FOUND DO

        SET n_total_price = n_total_price + PROD_PRICE;
        FETCH SUM_PRODUCTS INTO PROD_PRICE;
    END WHILE;

CLOSE SUM_PRODUCTS;
END
$$

DROP PROCEDURE P_TOTAL_PRICES;

CALL P_SELECT_TOTAL_SALARY(@A, @B);

Select @A;
SELECT @B;
```

Comment: The stored procedure that you define is called `P_TOTAL_PRICES` -- and you drop it.  Then you call another one, `P_SELECT_TOTAL_SALARY`.  Just call the right procedure.

Comment: . . I would suggest that you close the question.